# Cast your votes in the moderator elections before August 17!

Tags: discussion, election

This questions serves as an entry in the Community Bulletin for the ongoing moderator elections and a hub for related sites.

**Elections are over! Find the results [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/2015-community-moderator-election-results).**

The election chat has been archived [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26557/2015/8/3).

#### Former posts

- [Read candidate interviews!](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire)
- [Propose questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) for interviewing candidates!
- [Preparing for graduation: Election coming on August 3, 2015](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/preparing-for-graduation-election-coming-on-august-3-2015)
- [2015 Community Moderator Election](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/2015-community-moderator-election)